# Get ImageView content from an Accessibility Service on Android

Tags: android, imageview, accessibilityservice, getcontent

I am able to get an ImageView as an AccessibilityNodeInfo in my accessibility service but I am not able to get the content of this ImageView. I know on a TextView I can get the content with getText(), but is there a similar function to get content from ImageView as Drawable for exemple ?